# Python: How to get a value of sub key in Hash Table?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, hashtable

I'm new to python. I'm learning to get data from hash table which is stored in a file. Below is an example of the table I have:

```
{ 
"Technology": {"20809": 98},
"Movie":{"1193435": 1},
"Entertainment":{"13398": 76},
"Computer": {"28765": 54},
"Food": {"708": 4},
"Gasoline": {"358": 18},
"Material": {"98": 6},
"Water": {"3": 6}
}
```

Question:
How I can get a value of the sub key? For example, a value of the sub key `"708"` (under `"Food"`) is `4`. How can I get the number 4? I only know that if I use `variable.get(key)` I will get both sub key and a value of the sub key, but how only value? The following code is what I am trying to do. I want to pass an input to a function and return the value.

If I want to search for the values of sub keys in a huge amount of hash table, would this approach be efficient enough (fast enough)? Thank you.

```
def searchAtHashTable(input):        
    hashVal = # I read the hash value from a file by using .read()
    for key in hashVal.keys():
        if key == input:
           return sorted(hashVal.get(key))
```

Comment: Note: the default built-in type is called a dictionary, `dict` for short. Python calls the class of types, the interface, a mapping. They *happen* to be implemented in CPython as a hash table, but that's not a name you'll often see mentioned in the Python documentation or in tutorials.

Comment: Please consider splitting your questions into multiple posts as suggested http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts. Meaning, delete the part about efficiency in this question. You might want to open a new questions for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just chain the item syntax:

```
>>> outerdict['Food']['708']
4
```

If all you have is `'708'` you'd have to search:

```
def searchNestedKey(outerdict, key):
    for nesteddict in outerdict.itervalues():
        if key in nesteddict:
            return nesteddict[key]
```

This loops over all nested dictionaries (the values of `outerdict`) and if `key` is present in it, it'll return that value. If multiple dictionaries have the same key, which key is picked is undefined, as Python dictionaries do not promise a specific ordering.